# How to retrieve data from a member of a list of a dictionary using Angularjs?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a dictionary of the following structure :

```
Dictionary<string,List<B>> a;
```

where B is a class of the following structure:

```
public class B    
{
   public Int64 c;
   public Boolean d;
}
```

After doing some processing in the backend, I get **a** with the required data.

Now I would like to display *a part* of this data in the web page.

My code is as follows :

```
<div ng-repeat="(e,f) in a">
    <div ng-style="set_color(f)">  {{e}} -> {{f.c}}
        <div ng-show="showCorrectBox">
             <label>hello</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-ng-model="blahblah" placeholder="hello">
        </div>
        <br /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I am trying to display **e** and **f.c**.

If I try to display **f** instead, I see some JSON output for **f**. However, I only want to display a part of **f**, that is **f.c**.

I tried

1) **f.c**

2) **f["c"]**

Both don't work. What am I doing wrong?

I am new to Angularjs.

Comment: `f` in this case is `List<B>` so you just need yet one ng-repeat

Comment: @grundy : Could you please show me how to code that here?

Comment: can you provide sample for `a` and sample output? and also function `set_color`

Comment: So `a` is an object and you are using `ng-repeat` to loop into an object?

Comment: set_color is irrelevant for my question.  a is just a dictionary with a string based key and value having one int variable and one bool variable. I just want to display the string key and the int part of the value.

Comment: @yes ealon. If I try to display the key and value pair as a whole, I get the display. However, I want to display only a part of the value, that is, for every key, I want to display only the *int* part of the *list* value.

Comment: @SoulRayder Got it, thanks for your explanation. See Grundy's answer, you just need another `ng-repeat` for `f`.

Comment: @Ealon : Could you please answer the part of the question that I have posted as comment in grundy's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get from server

```
Dictionary<string,List<B>> a;
```

so in client side it would be object where values is array. in this case when you do

```
<div ng-repeat="(e,f) in a">
```

you get in `f` - array. To access concrete object from it you should do ng-repeat again

```
<div ng-repeat="(e,f) in a">
    <div ng-repeat="b in f" ng-style="set_color(b)">  {{e}} -> {{b.c}}
        <div ng-show="showCorrectBox">
             <label>hello</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-ng-model="blahblah" placeholder="hello">
        </div>
        <br /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a ton. How to display everything in a single line, that is  **e -> b.c,b.c,b.c** for all values b.c for a given e?

Comment: @SoulRayder Then you can use `span` instead of `div`.

Comment: @SoulRayder Glad to help. :)